# I want to write this MySql Query in Laravel Controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```sql
SELECT user_matches.*
FROM users u
JOIN user_matches
    ON u.id = user_matches.user_id AND 
        FIND_IN_SET(
            user_matches.to_user_id,
            (
                SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(users.id) FROM `users`
            )
        );
```

Comment: OK, you stated what you wanted. However, you did not ask any questions, so we cannot provide any answers. If your question is how to do the conversion from SQL query to laravel, you need to bear in mind that SO is not a free code writing service! You need to provide a reasonable attempt at solving the conversion yourself!

Comment: Am i confused with the weird sql functions called here, but arent you just trying to find user_matches that are also in the user table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::select('')
```

to write you raw query .

Comment: How to add created at in user_matches table?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$users = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::select(<<<SQL
SELECT user_matches.*
FROM users u
JOIN user_matches
    ON u.id = user_matches.user_id AND 
        FIND_IN_SET(
            user_matches.to_user_id,
            (
                SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(users.id) FROM `users`
            )
        );
SQL
);
```

Comment: How to add created at from user_matches table?